# How does TypeScript implement generic functions that can take generic function types as arguments?

Tags: typescript

How does TypeScript implement figuring out the type of an application of a polymorphic function to another polymoprhic function?

```
declare function map<T, U>(f: (t: T) => U, t: T[]): U[];
declare function id<Z>(t: Z): Z
const x = map(id, [1, 2, 3]) // x: [number]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAMwK4DsIBcCWB7dRAWxgAcAeAFQBpEBVAPgApkAuRJrdygSkQF4G9Wl0SUA2gF0e7OlIDcoSLAQoM2fIRwgqzUb27AIBAM5ZEADwHEyTbbXEBGWgCZaAZmmIA9N8vtxdFQiACMwOElgIA)

> Also, is there a name for this sort of feature?

What I'm looking for is a simple step-by-step description of the algorithm, with extraneous details stripped away. I peeked at the TS source, and there's a massive chain of helper functions with lots of logic to deal with OO stuff, special cases, and interaction with fancy features. But I imagine there is a simple way of explaining it.

I can't think of achieving this that doesn't involve constraint solving. That is (where `<:` means "subtype of"):

```
(Z => Z) <: (T => U)
number[] <: T
solve for U
```

But that's not what TS does, otherwise it would accept the following, with `x: number | string`:

```
declare function fn<T>(t1: T, t2: T): T;
declare const num: number
declare const str: string
const x = fn(num, str) // Error: string not assignable to number
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAMwK4DsIBcCWB7dFdAHgBUA+ACiwEYAuRUgGkSwCYHSBKTgblEiwEiCAQDOWROlQBbBtJkAjMHAHR4SUegmIJcBnpzoA5sC06AHogC8RSgpZ6uiAPQvEAUThw8+3VjgjYyk8SRgxMRxjdBhFKCQsPClZZVUgA)